# Rsync from remote Ubuntu server to WSL on Win11 fails with "unexplained error (code 255)" after exactly 90 seconds

Tags: ssh, rsync

Okay, so I have a small minecraft server in my basement running Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-87-generic x86_64)

I have a Windows 11 machine upstairs with WSL installed. Everything is maximally updated.

I am trying to make it so that when I boot my Windows PC, WSL kicks in and performs an rsync, grabbing everything from the little server and copying to an external drive on my Win11 machine. And I got it! It works! But the connection drops after 90 seconds and I have tried a lot of stuff to fix it, and have failed.

Things I've tried:

I am using values of

- `TCPKeepAlive yes` in all instances of `sshd_config` and `ssh_config` (both server and wsl)
- `ServerAliveInterval 15` in all instances of `ssh_config`
- `ServerAliveCountMax 3` in all instances of `ssh_config`
- `ClientAliveInterval 600` in all instances of `sshd_config`
- `ClientAliveCountMax 0` in all instances of `sshd_config`
- `--timeout=600` rsync flag
- disabled UFW (`sudo ufw disable`) in both WSL and remote server
- Disabled Windows firewall
- explicitly forwarded my SSH port in my router
- made sure Windows was set to private connection, not public

Literally none of those options have changed the 90 second timeout, so I guess the next question I can pose to the community... Does anyone know of anything that defaults to a 90 second timeout? Maybe it can be narrowed down that way

I had begun making a guide on reddit which I thought was complete, so I'm going to post that guide here so that there's reference to where I'm at and what I've done.

### Begin Reddit Post

Okay, I was able to get it so that Windows pulls the changes on boot. I'm writing out a guide here mostly because I know I'm gonna need this again later and I don't want to spend all day figuring out how I did it lol

### Windows

We'll be backing up to an external drive located on the Windows PC, and the backup will begin whenever a certain user logs in.

I changed my backup drive to the letter Z, I won't go over how to do that in this guide.

**To initiate backup**

1. Navigate to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`
   and create a new `.bat` file with the following contents, can be any name.
   `wsl -u root sudo service backup start`
   This `.bat` file will automatically start when the user is logging in just by being in this folder.

### WSL

**To prevent password prompting:**

1. `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers.d/backup`
   and add
   `%sudo ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service backup start`
2. Make sure WSL has passwordless ssh access to the remote server (meaning you can SSH into the remote server from WSL without getting a password prompt). I also will not go over how to set up hostkey pair verification.

**Creating the service**

This will back up the `test` folder located inside the remote server's home folder
It will run on port 22 and if files are deleted on the server, the next backup will delete the files from the backup. remove the `--delete` parameter if you never want your backup to delete anything.

1. `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/backup.service`

   and add

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=MyBackup

    [Service]
    User=<WSL Username Here, must be run as a user so rsync can use hostkey verification>
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync --timeout=600 -arvz -e 'ssh -p 22' --progress --delete <remoteUser>@<remoteIP>:/home/<remoteHomeFolder>/test /mnt/z/ --log-file /mnt/z/rsync.log        
    Type=forking

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Run this to load our new service, ready to be started by the `.bat` file
   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Once these changes are complete, I recommend restarting. If you do something like change the drive letter to your backup like I did, WSL does not recognize the new drive letter until you restart anyway, and by restarting you should trigger the backup correctly.

Edit:
Apparently this isn't a full solution, as rsync disconnects after 90 seconds

```
2023/10/23 16:26:33 [467] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(713) [generator=3.2.7]
2023/10/23 16:26:33 [481] rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(1613) [receiver=3.2.7]
2023/10/23 16:26:33 [467] rsync: [generator] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

Googling this has lead me to a dead end.

### End Reddit Post

So there you go. I hope it's detailed enough, this issue is stressing me out and I want it solved.

Comment: Have you tried changing your rsync options from `-arvz` to something more "simple" such as `-rv` for example, to disable any compression and archiving options. Perhaps try removing the `--progress` or `--delete` options, try adding `--checksum` to change rsync file comparison method. I have no experience using rsync to/from Windows but I have going to/from some cloud services and sometimes certain services or file system types just don't/can't support certain features of rsync.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this question; I have enjoyed pondering it. I would guess that it's a issue with the SSH connection, based on these messages:

`unexplained error (code 255)` - probably means SSH is telling rsync that the connection failed?

`write error: Broken pipe (32)` - This usually means the connection is closed but we are still trying to write to it.

Try changing the command to remove excessive messages from rsync and focus on the SSH debugging:

`rsync`: remove `-v` and `--progress`, also `-r` is implied with `-a`, and `-z` is not necessary over Ethernet.

`SSH`: add `-vvv`

Example:
`rsync -a -e 'ssh -vvv' --delete user@ipaddr:/src /dst --log-file rsync.log`

Failing that, you might have to fire up `WireShark` to get some more info. You could also try connecting over `wireguard`, since traffic sent will be over UDP, which might rule out any other issues caused by any advanced/buggy networking devices.

Comment: Thanks, but none of that helped. I have a suspicion that the 90 second timeout is somewhere within WSL. I ended up just connecting the backup directly to the server and rsyncing that way. I really wanted it to be off-site without purchasing more equipment, but oh well, it's unlikely anything'll go wrong anyway (famous last words)